# Adding KeyEventListeners to JFrame from External Jar?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a class project here where I must make a working Asteroids game. Right now I'm stuck on getting key events to even be recognized. I've read and watched tutorials and had those working, but implementing the same thing in this environment isn't helping. I'm hoping maybe someone can guide me in the right direction.

This here is the main class that implements KeyListener with key action methods which makes my Ship object and sets up a "sandbox". "Sandbox" being the Jframe that displays the objects. "Sandbox" is imported from an external jar I received in class as well as other things from "blobfx.jar".

```
package Asteroid;

import java.util.Random;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import blobfx.SandBox;
import blobfx.SandBoxMode;



public class AsteroidMain implements KeyListener{
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ currently has error: "The type AsteroidMain must implement the inherited abstract method KeyListener.keyPressed(KeyEvent)"

private static Random random = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {


    SandBox sb = new SandBox();
    sb.setFrameRate(66);
    // makes window for objects at frame rate of 15


    Ship shipThing = new Ship();
    sb.addBlob( shipThing );
    // makes ship object then adds it to the window

    SandBox.simulate(sb);
    // draws the objects on screen

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e, Ship shipThing) {
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ currently has error: "The method keyPressed(KeyEvent, Ship) of type AsteroidMain must override or implement a supertype method"
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 38){
        shipThing.moveForward(); 
        System.out.println("KEY PRESSED");
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}


@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

And here is my Ship class that I want to get moving forward when the UP key is pressed.

```
package Asteroid;

import java.lang.Math;

import blobfx.PolyBlob;


public class Ship extends PolyBlob{

private double angle = 0.0;
private final double delta = 0.15;
private final double speed = 5.0;


public Ship( ){

    super(0,0,0);

    int x[] = {10, -10, -5, -10};
    int y[] = { 0,  -7,  0,   7};
    setPolygon( x, y );
    // sets vertices that draws the ship polygon

    setLoc( 200, 200 );

}

public void moveForward(){

    System.out.println( "MOVING FORWARD");

    setLoc( getLoc().x + (int) Math.round(speed * Math.cos(angle)), 
            getLoc().y + (int) Math.round(speed * Math.sin(angle))
            );
}

public void turnLeft(){

}

public void turnRight(){

}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at the JavaDocs for [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html)

You are violating the contractual requirements of the interface by not implementing [`keyPressed(KeyEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent))

This...

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e, Ship shipThing) {
```

Should have given you a compiler error, telling you that you  weren't overriding a method and it should be

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
```

You can't just "invent" parameters, the interface describes the expected requirements that must be meet by any implementation

Having said that, I would strongly discourage the use of `KeyListener` in favor of the Key Bindings API, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: I'm not inventing parameters. I'm passing my Ship object to the keyPressed() so it can run the method in my Ship class. `shipThing.moveForward();`

Is my implementation wrong here? Should I put the key listeners in my Ship class?

Comment: No, that's not how it works.  A `KeyEvent` will be triggered, at some time and then you need to respond to it.  The management of the key event and the movement of you ship should be handled by a centralized update-loop

Comment: Have you actually attached the `KeyListener` to anything that is displayable on the screen?  Like the main window?  Or the main component?

Comment: Yeah, I have `implements KeyListener` to respond to my key events, but I can't get any action to happen as a result. I've done `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  if(e.getKeyCode() == 38){
   System.out.println("KEY PRESSED");
  }
 }`

So when I press the UP key it should print that to console, right? I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I think its missing `addKeyListener(this);` but I don't know where to put it where it wont error.

Comment: `this` doesn't have a `addKeyListener` method, so it's not capable of generating key events.  While I'd still discourage you from using `KeyListener`, take a look at [How to Write a Key Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: I'm still totally lost. I've been following tutorials like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FZxXrovYFk

But I don't understand how to implement it into my environment. I now have `sb.addKeyListener()` in my main but I get an error saying its undefined which I don't know what it means. I do actually. But how do I define it? 

These tutorials make sense when I do them by it self, but I can't figure out how to add it here to what I have.

Comment: You see, we have this black hole called `blobfx.jar`, we have NO idea what it is or what it contains.  You need to find some component which has a `addKeyListener` method and "hope" that it's actually attached to the UI which is displayed on the screen and "hope" that it has focus in order to register key events.  Beyond that, what I've suggested is about as far as we can help

Comment: This is the first time I've done anything with Java or KeyEvents so I'm totally lost on what proper implementation should be. I have the documentation, but I have no clue how to read it. The doc says the jar has `public interface BlobAction{ void keyAction(KeyEvent e) //Keyboard event handler }` but I have no clue how to use it so I've been watching video tutorials in general.

Comment: I don't think the tuts are going to help you as the API seems to have it's own key handling process